# ng-grid -- on "edit" button click --> on modal.open , popup will open --> need to show "drop down list for 1 of the field."

Tags: drop-down-menu, ng-grid

ng-grid -- on "edit" button click --> on modal.open , popup will open --> need to show "drop down list for 1 of the field."

Note :-
1. I don't want inline editing
2. Want to open a "modal"/"popup"  show dropdown list

Somehow i manage to show dropdown list but on DDL select , other field data is blank and DDL data contain wrong data. e.g if i bind "name' it contain "id"=0,1.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Maybe look at the 3.x version of ng-grid, now called ui-grid. It's still beta but has dropdown fields built in. Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245495/using-an-ng-option-dropdown-in-a-ui-grid-editablecelltemplate-ng-grid-3-x