# EditableCellTemplate in ui-grid stuck in edit mode [ng-grid 3.X]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grid, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

this is a slight continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245495/using-an-ng-option-dropdown-in-a-ui-grid-editablecelltemplate-ng-grid-3-x).

I am working with ng-grids new release [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) and am having an issue with editableCellTemplate. I 
am using the template to show a dynamic dropdown list using ng-options for editing. This works fine, however the cell seems to get stuck in edit mode. I have seen this issue before on stack overflow in relation to older versions of ng-grid. (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680363/angularjs-ng-grid-editablecelltemplate-remains-in-edit-mode-on-loss-of-focus) post)

Those solutions usually end up pointing out that they forgot to use `ng-input="COL_FIELD"` in their select.

I have tried such methods, but it does not seem to be working for ui-grid. Perhaps it's because I am using ng-options and the other examples were not? Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qu6S5WORIOS79mpr2Ve2?p=preview) of the dropdown in the grid. Notice how if you lose focus, the cell still stays in edit mode.

Has anyone came across this problem with ui-grid and conquered it? If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace **ng-cell-input** with **ui-grid-edit-dropdown**

[Here is Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PSrhIUQ7EJqgFaR8Kce1?p=preview)

BTW, This is [default template](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/v3.0.0-rc.12/src/features/edit/templates/dropdownEditor.html)

```
<div>
  <form name="inputForm">
    <select ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" ui-grid-edit-dropdown ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-options="field[editDropdownIdLabel] as field[editDropdownValueLabel] CUSTOM_FILTERS for field in editDropdownOptionsArray"></select>
  </form>
</div>
```

If no reason, maybe don't need custom template, check [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little update to the answer from @allyusd which is generally right but the plunker is not working correctly after you blur the cell.

Change the template to:

```
<div>
    <select ui-grid-edit-dropdown ng-class="'colt' + $index" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" data-ng-options="d.type as d.type for d in getExternalScopes().genderTypes">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Gender</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Especially the part `data-ng-options="d.type as d.type...`

This will pass only the type into your model.

See the (slightly) forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l36gX7OXkCCa4R8Cx4Ru?p=preview) here. (Note that I added some debug info after the grid again)

Don't regard this as an answer. It's just a mild correction to allyusds answer.